# How to get the data which is inside a unique id in firebase

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
```

There's a unique id for each user inside Users child... inside that is the data o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate inside the unique id to be able to get the data there:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
 String name=datas.child("name").getValue().toString();
   //gets data
  }
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
  }
});
```

Example if you have:

```
 Users
  uniqueid
     name: peter
```

The above will iterate inside the unique id and give you the name "peter"